# C# - UTC automatically convert to 12h system

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I'm working with a project and one of its functional requirement is to create a datetime range in which I will select a set of data based on that.

This range should take today's datetime starting from 8:00:00 to 18:00:00, and then I want to convert the format to be `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ`, so I'm doing the following to approach that:

```
DateTime fromTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(8,0,0);
fromTime = fromTime.Date + ts;
string fromTimeFormat = fromTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
DateTime toTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan tss = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0);
toTime = toTime.Date + tss;
string toTimeFormat = toTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
```

The problem is that, the `toTimeFormat` is being converted to the 12h system, so when I use it later it's being considered as 6:00 AM.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hhSpecifier) which is for [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) format.

You need to use [`HH` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifierhttp://) which is for [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) format.

```
string toTimeFormat = toTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

And you can simplify your code as;

```
string fromTimeFormat = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");   
string toTimeFormat = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

Comment: Worked!, great thanks